# Is a stopped martingale always a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

If $M_t$ is a continuous martingale, and $T$ arbitrary stopping time, is $M_t^T$ a martingale? Does this stay true when we only have right-continuity? I know it's true when the stopping time is bounded, but I am interested about this in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $(M_t)_{t\in\mathbb R_+}$ is a right-continuous martingale and $T$ is a stopping time, then $(M_{t\land T})_{t\in\mathbb R_+}$ also is a martingale, see for instance Corollary 3.24 in Le Gall, *Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus*, 2016.

Comment: Also proved in p.325 of Chung's A Course in Probability Theory.